# Unobtrusive date compare validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

So I've been following this tutorial [here](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/05/validating-dependent-fields-in-asp-net-mvc) and it shows you how to validate dates compared with each other. I'm getting an error in the first block of code which I've commented and it says "Unable to get property 'element' of undefined or null reference" which originates from this line of code customValidation.formValidator = $(event.data.source).closest('form').data('validator') does anyone know of a work around for this so I don't get an error. I'm using the latest unobtrusive validation

```
window.customValidation = window.customValidation ||
{
    relatedControlValidationCalled: function (event) {
        if (!customValidation.activeValidator) {
            customValidation.formValidator = $(event.data.source).closest('form').data('validator');
        }

        // code error below
        customValidation.formValidator.element($(event.data.target));
    },
    relatedControlCollection: [],
    formValidator: undefined,
    addDependatControlValidaitonHandler: function (element, dependentPropertyName) {
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(id, customValidation.relatedControlCollection) < 0) {
            customValidation.relatedControlCollection.push(id);
            $(element).on(
                'blur',
                { source: $(element), target: $('#' + dependentPropertyName) },
                customValidation.relatedControlValidationCalled);
        }
    }
};
```

adapter:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('comparedates', ['otherpropertyname', 'allowequality'],
    function (options) {
        options.rules['comparedates'] = options.params;
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages['comparedates'] = options.message;
        }
    }
);
```

validator method:

```
$.validator.addMethod('comparedates', function (value, element, params) {
    var otherFieldValue = $('input[name="' + params.otherpropertyname + '"]').val();
    if (otherFieldValue && value) {
        var currentValue = Date.parse(value);
        var otherValue = Date.parse(otherFieldValue);
        if ($(element).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf('begin') >= 0) {
            if (params.allowequality) {
                if (currentValue > otherValue) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentValue >= otherValue) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (params.allowequality) {
                if (currentValue < otherValue) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentValue <= otherValue) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    customValidation.addDependatControlValidaitonHandler(element, params.otherpropertyname);
    return true;
}, '');
```

Comment: grab a cdn link for validator plugin and create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are loading this code too early, before the form is in the DOM.  Make sure your code is protected by $(document).ready(your code here);